# Why did GS unilaterally delete my answer?

Tags: discussion

I cited Reddit wherefrom I quoted my answer at  https://money.stackexchange.com/a/110863.

Answer (score 4):

I linked to the [Help Center article about this](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/referencing):

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their
>   words and ideas to support your own.